# My output should be latest updated date

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM AUDIT;

 PROCESS     TIME      INDICATOR
----------  ---------  ---------
    1.1    01-MAR-14     A
    1.2    01-APR-14     A
    1.3    01-APR-14     A
    1.2    01-MAY-14     B
    1.2    01-JUN-14     A
    1.4    01-APR-14     B
```

My data is above format and if I will modify anything on this data and then whenever i will query from table, I should get latest modified date data.

Comment: Add an order by clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT * FROM AUDIT ORDER BY TimeColumn desc )
 WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle 12c** introduced the **Top-n** query. So, you could do it in a **single SQL** without using a **sub-query** for **ROWNUM**.

```
SELECT * FROM AUDIT
ORDER BY TIME DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Comment: But Lalit If my requirement is like recent updated month record, suppose somebody updated on APR month then my output should be APR month record only, If updated on MAR then only MAR should come.. how we will get that could you please help me on this..

Comment: @RanjanJena But you have already accepted an answer which gives you random row and not for a specific month. In that case, you need to add a filter using `WHERE` clause.